# JSP class declaration causing syntax error

Tags: class, jsp

The following Class Declaration at the start of my JSP file is causing Syntax error which is seen in Chrome Console.

```
    <%  
      class Events
    {
          int id { get; set; }
          String title { get; set; }
          String start { get; set; }
          String end { get; set; }

          Events(int id2, String I, String t, String ds)
        {
            this.id = id2;
            this.title = I;
            this.start = t;
            this.end = ds;
        }
    }
%>
```

The Error message is `Syntax error on token &quot;{&quot;, , expected`. On Removing the Toke `PUBLIC` I am getting this error `Syntax error on token &quot;{&quot;, , expected`.

Please advise to correct the errors.
PS: I am not Using IDE such as Eclipse or STS, for coding.

Comment: Why? Why not just declare it in a .java file of its own?

Comment: I tried that but didn't how to include it in my jsp file.... and that too was throwing error.

Comment: Also, just because this is a small class, its easier to manage. So please advise how to..

Answer (score 0):

Its matter of organizing the files. I Created a new .java file and named it `Events.java` and placed it in a folder called `Classes` under `WEB-INF` of my project folder. The contents of `Events.java` is like this

```
public class Events
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public String title { get; set; }
    public String start { get; set; }
    public String end { get; set; }

    public Events(int id2, String I, String t, String ds)
    {
        this.id = id2;
        this.title = I;
        this.start = t;
        this.end = ds;
    }
}
```

This Events.java is placed in Tomcat's installaition folder which looks like this

```
<drive Name:\>Tomcat Ver 8\webapps\ROOT\myprojectfolder\WEB-INF\Classes\
```

The file Events.java is in Classes folder as per the path given above.

In the .jsp file where I want this Events.java to be called, I made statement like this

```
<%@page import="Events.*"%>
```

... and it works fine.